# PHP _POST Data from Form

Tags: php, mysql

I have this form that I'm creating using PHP. The names of the form elements are a number

```
<form method="post" action="keywords.php">
    <?php
    echo $question
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <?php
    foreach ($orderexplode as $o) 
    {
        switch ($o) {
            case 0:
                print(" " . "<label>" . $presetwords[$i] . "</label>" . " ");
                $i++;
                break;
            case 1:
                print(" " . "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='$k' id ='$k'placeholder=" . $responsewords[$k] . ">" . " ");
                $k++;
                echo $k;
                break;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <br>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-info'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

How would I go about getting the value of each input box I want to check if it matches `$exploded` string?

```
$string = "Hello How Are You"
$explodedstring = explode(" ",$string)
```

Comment: using the `in_array` function of PHP

Comment: Do you mean you will have four input fields, and one of the word must be put into each of them? Do all words need to be used, or can some be left out/used twice? Or do you want them all, and in a specific order?

Comment: @CBroe I want them all the be used in the specific order

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use array indexes. You need to use indexes:

```
<?php
foreach ($orderexplode as $k => $o) 
{
    print(" " . "<label>" . $k . "</label>" . " ");
    print(" " . "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='" . $k . "' id ='" . $k . "'placeholder=" . $o . ">" . " ");
}
?>
```